# Change DockPanel Visibility on MouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change Visibility.Visible to Visibility.Collapsed and vice-versa when Background is not Black.
The code works fine if I use Opacity instead Visibility.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
    <Grid Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="36" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="36" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="36" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Name="BottomPanel" Style="{StaticResource Panel}" Background="Black" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  Panel.ZIndex="100">
        <Button Name="btn" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="BTN1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.557,14.529"/>
        <Button Name="btn2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="BTN2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Click="btn2_Click"/>
        <Button Name="btn3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="BTN3" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Click="btn3_Click"/>          
    </DockPanel>  
</Grid>


<Style x:Key="Panel" TargetType="DockPanel">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>

        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 5):

whenever a control is Hidden or Collapsed it will stop processing any inputs, so you won't trigger any triggers but You could use the Opacity property to implement the behavior

```
        <Style x:Key="Panel" TargetType="DockPanel">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Your code works but creates another problem. If the color is anything other than Balck, MouseOver won't trigger to show/hide the Panel. Sorry that I wasn't explicit enough. If the color if not Black, I want the panel to show/hide on MouseOver.

Comment: yes.i just explain why your DockPanel is always visible

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. I removed Visibility="Visible" and added your style but It didn't solve my problem.

Comment: i see your problem,check again

Comment: I know it works with Opacity, but I I wanted to use Visibility.Collapsed so that the buttons inside the DockPanel won't be accesible in any way.
My original code with Opacity: [link](https://pastebin.com/hgVFeW52)